# Facebook API retrieve "All activity"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the equivalent of what's shown on https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity. Both FQL & Open Graph are fine.

On the graph, `/me/feed` shows something similar, but it's missing likes, and tags and other things.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There is no endpoint to get to this data.

The only available data will be anything that appears as a post (e.g. Youtube, Twitter). For this you can query `stream` via FQL. You can also try endpoints `/music.listens` and `/video.watches` but they will retrive data for the current application not all.